# Module that prints first m positive odd integers and returns the square root of the sum of them

Tags: programming, syntax, homework

I am working on this problem and I feel like I've come so close.

Write a module that takes as input a positive integer m, prints the first m positive odd numbers and returns the square root of the sum of the numbers it printed.

This is what I have so far:

```
kellyrocks[m_]:=Module[{index,sum},index=0;sum=0;

If[Or[m<= 0,IntegerQ[m]==False],Return["Please enter a positive integer"]];

While[index<=m,sum=sum+index;index=2*index+1];

Return[sqrt[sum]]]
```

But when I try to run it I'm not getting what I should, ex:

```
kellyrocks[22]

sqrt[26]
```

I'm very new to mathematica and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I also am not sure about printing each number. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4):

```
g[n_Integer?(Positive@# &)] := (Print@#; Sqrt@Tr@#) &@Range[1, 2 n - 1, 2]

g[3]

(*
  {1,3,5}
  3
*)
```

Comment: The square root of 9 (1+3+5) is certainly not 35

Comment: @RunnyKine I was running a social experiment :)

Comment: But, but, the square root of 9 is 3. It should be `Sqrt@Tr@#`

Comment: @RunnyKine Damn. You're too clever. Clearly an outlier :)

Comment: Lol. You need a control experiment. +1

Comment: @RunnyKine Was typing from my phone while driving. Now that I left the highway I hope to make less mistakes :)

Comment: The answer is always going to be an integer, in fact, its always going to be `n`, so the `N` is probably not required.

Comment: I got some help from my friend who is a computer science major! It works now! I don't want to post the exact answer because I'm not the only one with this assignment and I don't just want to give it away. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @Kelly Oh, well. I disagree. You came here seeking for help and you should pay with the same coin you got.

Comment: The LHS can be shortened to `g[n_Integer?Positive]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Sure, I was just trying to show the general form to enable the OP to add further validations

Comment: @Dr.belisarius, "Was typing from my phone while driving." Scariest thing I've read in a while. I hope you were joking.

Comment: @TimothyWofford of course .p.  I don't program and drive